# Python Discord Bot How To Send Multiple Lines In One Message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Hey I am trying to take messages that has multiple lines, add text to the start and end of each line, then resend the lines as one message. The main problem is I am having trouble with sending multiple lines in one message. Could someone please help me? I will include my desired output so you know what i mean. Thanks so much.

Code I am currently using that sends individual messages

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        channel = client.get_channel(754584125108912150) #change to your channel id
        if message.channel.id == channel.id:
            if "placeholder first line" in message.content.lower():
                messagee = message.content.split('\n')
                for line in messagee:
                    testt = "test_start "+line+" test_end"
                    await channel.send(testt)

client = MyClient()
client.run(TOKENHERE) #bot token here
```

Current individual output messages sending:

```
BOT_username Today at 9:41 AM
test_start apple first line test_end

BOT_username Today at 9:41 AM
test_start week test_end

BOT_username Today at 9:41 AM
test_start food test_end

BOT_username Today at 9:41 AM
test_start fork test_end

etc..
```

Desired single message sent:

```
BOT_username Today at 9:41 AM
test_start apple first line test_end
test_start week test_end
test_start food test_end
test_start fork test_end
```

Comment: So what you are trying to do is take a message, and just add something to the front and back of it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your bot posts multiple messages is because your await is inside a loop.

You can avoid using the loop altogether

```
messagee = message.content.split('\n')
output_text = '\n'.join(('test_start' + line + 'test_end') for line in messagee)
await channel.send(output_text)
```